# How to compare a server variable In .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Im having some seriously frustrating issues getting my website to redirect from http to https. Cloudflare seems to be messing a lot of the server variables up so the standard if port 80 redirect thing doesnt work for me and i keep getting stuck in a redirect loop. I have found a way around this by adding some php to the index.php of the wordpress site.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == "http") 
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
    die();
}
```

This works, but i would rather do this in the htaccess file as it will be faster than having to parse php code and then do the redirect. I have tried to do it, but i keep getting an error 500 when i make any changes. So far i have tried

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO} =="http"
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: I think you are getting 500error because of the invalid syntex **==**  (double ==) On mod rewrite you need just 1 **=** to compare a string Lexicographically

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
```